# aws DynamoDb Boto adding a new item to a table

Tags: database, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am working to add items to a dynamodb database using python (boto api). I saw examples of people creating items and storing them using the table.new_item method. 
Ex:

```
dynamoConn = boto.connect_dynamodb(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
dTable = dynamoConn.get_table(aws_dynamo_table)
....
item_data = {}
....
dTable.new_item(loc, theNewKey, item_data)
```

The code runs, I do not find any errors and when tracing through using debugger I do not see any reason why my item, a hash of keys and text values can't be stored.

I read: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html
However I think I may be missing an "update table" function. I'm not seeing one nor can I find an example of one online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new_item` method returns an `Item` object that is ready to be saved to DynamoDB but it doesn't actually save it for you.  Once you are ready to save the item, you need to call the `save` (UpdateItem) or `put` (PutItem) method of the `Item` object.